# MySQL C API: Need example for initiating DB on *Embedded* mode

Tags: mysql, c, embedded-database

I work on a **C** tool, in which I need to manipulate and query process-internal data intensively.

Hence, I've decided to use the **MySQL C API** on **Embedded** mode, so I can have an embedded DB for each running process of my tool, and use all the SQL features on it.

All the **MySQL C API** tutorials I've found over the web, deal with connecting to a running server, which is not my case.

There are some examples for working with **Embedded** mode in Oracle's MySQL website, but they are not simple, and it's hard to make them work.

Q: Can someone please point me or write me a short example for initiating a DB using **MySQL C API** on **Embedded** mode?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of tries, finally answering to myself and sharing it with you:

- Create a central data directory that would be used for storing DBs. In this example, I'll use `/tmp/mysql_embedded_data`

`> mkdir /tmp/mysql_embedded_data`

- Create a C file, as in the following example:

```c
#include <my_global.h>
#include <mysql.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {  
    static char *server_options[] = {
                                   "mysql_test", // An unused string 
                                    "--datadir=/tmp/mysql_embedded_data", // Your data dir
                                    NULL };
    int num_elements = (sizeof(server_options) / sizeof(char *)) - 1;

    static char *server_groups[] = { "libmysqld_server",
                                     "libmysqld_client", NULL };


    // Init MySQL lib and connection    
    mysql_library_init(num_elements, server_options, server_groups);
    MYSQL *con = mysql_init(NULL);

    if (con == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(con));
        exit(1);
    }

    mysql_options(con, MYSQL_READ_DEFAULT_GROUP, "libmysqld_client");
    mysql_options(con, MYSQL_OPT_USE_EMBEDDED_CONNECTION, NULL);

    // Connect to no host/port -> Embedded mode
    if (mysql_real_connect(con, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, 0) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(con));
        mysql_close(con);
        exit(1);
    }

    // Create a sample empty DB, named "aNewDatabase"
    if (mysql_query(con, "CREATE DATABASE aNewDatabase")) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(con));
        mysql_close(con);
        exit(1);
    }

    // Close connection
    mysql_close(con);
    exit(0);
}
```

- Compile your file (I assume in this example that my C filename is `/tmp/mysql_try.c`)

`` gcc /tmp/mysql_try.c -o /tmp/mysql_try -lz `mysql_config --include --libmysqld-libs` ``

- Run your compiled program:

`> /tmp/mysql_try`

- When your program returnes, ensure that the DB creation succeeded. We named our sample DB `aNewDatabase`, so we'll check if it now has a directory inside the data directory we created -> We'll check if the directory `/tmp/mysql_embedded_data/aNewDatabase` was created:

`> ls /tmp/mysql_embedded_data/aNewDatabase
db.opt`

- Enjoy!